# DirectX 11 Depth Rendering

Tags: directx, render, directx-11, depth

Is it possible to get the depth values from the depth stencil buffer? Right now, I have a depth shader that renders the distance of each pixel using 1.0f - (outputPosition.z / outputPosition.w) from the vertex shader.

Comment: Sure. Where do you want to read the value? On the CPU or in a shader?

Comment: When you create the depth/stencil buffer, you can set the bind flags for different uses. So you can set them to depth/stencil buffer and shader resource at the same time. Then create two views, one DSV and one SRV. After rendering to DSV you can attach it to the pipeline as SRV and read its content.